# Ensuring the integrity of a user's 'balance' in a Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design, transactions, marketplace

'Balance' represents the difference between the sum of credits, and the sum of debits. The following simplified schema represents an example:

[Schema http://dl.dropbox.com/u/10177092/Personal/stackoverflow_question.png](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/10177092/Personal/stackoverflow_question.png)

Note the 'balance' column. I have identified three approaches to determining balance:

(1) When updating the credit or debit table (and updating the balance), wrap the code in a [Transaction block](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html). For example:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  current_user.credits.credit(100)
  current_user.balance.increment(100)
end
```

(2) Don't include a 'balance' column - instead, calculate the balance each time it is requested:

```
credit = current_user.credits.sum('amount')
debit = current_user.debits.sum('amount')
balance = credits - debits
```

(3) Create a [database view](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/View_(database)).

I would appreciate advice regarding:

- The advantages and disadvantages of each approach.
- Alternative approaches.

It seems to me like calculating balance (e.g. 2. and 3.) best ensure the integrity of the value. However, I am concerned (2) may become inefficient as users engage in additional transactions. Database views seem like a theoretically sound option, but I don't believe [rails_sql_views](https://github.com/aeden/rails_sql_views) supports Rails 3, and I have noticed several threads that imply database views are undesirable/often associated with legacy databases.

Answer (score 3):

Create a **Movement** model.

```
user_id, quantity, balance, updated_at, created_at
```

Define add_credit, add_debit and balance instance methods in **User** model:

```
 def add_credit(quantity)   
    self.movements.create :quantity => quantity 
 end

 def add_debit(quantity)
    self.movements.create :quantity => -quantity
end

def balance
  self.movements.last.balance
end
```

Use an after_save callback in **Movement** model:

```
before_save :update_balance

def update_balance
    if balance
       balance = self.user.movements.last.balance + self.quantity 
    else
       balance = self.quantity # First movement
    end
end
```

This way you assure that when credit or debit is added, the balance is updated because it's contained in the same credit/debit movement object.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately my simplified use-case didn't reflect that credits and debits must be in separate tables. In my app, 'debits' represent purchases by a user. This purchase belongs_to an item. 'Credits' represent transactions wherein the user has deposited funds via credit card (this table also requires an additional 'authorization' column). These two tables - transactions and purchases - are logically distinct and shouldn't be combined into a single model. Sorry for not explaining this in my question - I was trying to keep things simple to increase clarity.